# Sort DRF serializer output of DictField by key

Tags: django, sorting, dictionary, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a Django Rest Framework serializer that uses a `DictField`:

```
class FlatArticleSerializer(Serializer):
    attributes = DictField(child=FlatArticleAttributeSerializer())
```

The output is all the time different, since the attributes are a dictionary, which is by definition not sorted. Is there a way to sort these in the output nevertheless, alphabetically on string for instance?

Comment: have you tried a method field? The method would take in the data and return back a sorted dict

Comment: I was considering that, but then I don't get deserialization for free anymore. Now, if I input a dictionary, the object is created.

Comment: then you may use a nested serializer as suggested in Jahongir's response, and set the `order_by` attribute in your nestedd serializer to sort your data. Would it work in your case?

Answer (score 1):

If the internal value is stored in an `OrderedDict` the keys will be in order of the `OrderedDict`. You could post-process this in `to_representation` like so:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):

    representation = super().to_representation(instance)

    attributes_dict = representation['attributes']
    attribute_keys_sorted = sorted(attributes_dict.keys())

    # Build ordered dictionary with sorted keys
    sorted_attribute_dict = OrderedDict()
    for key in attribute_keys_sorted:
        sorted_attribute_dict[key] = attributes_dict[key]

    representation['attributes'] = sorted_attribute_dict

    return representation
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a nested serializer instead? I believe it will sort the keys as dictated by the `fields` of your serializer:

```
class FlatArticleSerializer(Serializer):
    attributes = FlatArticleAttributeSerializer()
```

Comment: Because the keys are not set in FlatArticleAttributes, so that serializer doesn't know the keys.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
class Meta:
  order_by = (('attributes',))
```

This will sort the data as per the attributes field

Comment: Where would I put this? Serializers don't have an `order_by` keyword in `Meta`.